# Security holes in in PHP 5.2.5

Tags: php, security

My shared hosting provider uses PHP 5.2.5, which was released at the end of 2007. I would like to know the security holes of PHP 5.2.5. Where I can get them?

[phpinfo](http://krumovgrad.eu/phpinfo.php)

Comment: The first one is letting everyone know that the phpinfo file is public on your server

Comment: Have to agree with @Michael B. - remove that file ASAP.

Comment: Ask your provider to install a more recent version of PHP. The [PHP5.2 branch has officially reached End Of Support as of Dec, 16 2010](http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-12-16-1). Everyone is encouraged to upgrade to the PHP 5.3 branch.

Comment: You might be in luck over at http://security.stackexchange.com/ aswell

Comment: @Michael B., feel free to hack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP ChangeLog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) ... check anything above 5.2.5 in 5.2.x series only..

Answer (score 2):

Curiously enough, specific security issues aren't often published (otherwise they'd be very easy to exploit), but you can generally get an idea from the [changelogs](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.16) for subsequent releases.

Answer (score 1):

Vulnerabilities are on this page:

http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/29009/references

Answer (score 1):

If you are after really long and extensive list go here: [security focus](http://www.securityfocus.com/vulnerabilities), if you are just after publicly available exploits, you may wanna search [exploitdb](http://www.exploit-db.com).
There is nothing major from what I've seen so far.